# React Native Release APK only Android Crash

Tags: android, react-native, crash-reports

My apk-debug works fine!

Build apk-release works fine!

When I install to device the app crash and start with this issue:

adb logcat

```
E AndroidRuntime: Process: br.com.missionbrasil, PID: 10382
E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement. (index.android.bundle:4)
E AndroidRuntime:   at com.facebook.react.bridge.DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.java:24)
E AndroidRuntime:   at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DisabledDevSupportManager.handleException(DisabledDevSupportManager.java:172)
E AndroidRuntime:   ... 7 more
W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity br.com.missionbrasil/.MainActivity
```

I change all conditions => `{ vars && (<View></View>) } to { vars ?: }`

Clean ./gradlew 100 times...

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/react-native-fade-in-image": "^1.1.1",
    "@expo/react-native-touchable-native-feedback-safe": "^1.1.2",
    "autobind-decorator": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.2",
    "react-native": "^0.51.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.19.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

Anyone have this same issue?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

*SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement*

Follow the steps outlined below to search and replace 3 strings in your node_modules folder:

> **Step 1 | NativeModules.js**

- GO TO: `/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/BatchedBridgedModules/NativeModules.js`
- FIND: `function normalizePrefix(moduleName: string)`
- REPLACE WITH: `const normalizePrefix = function(moduleName: string)`

> **Step 2 | UIManager.js**

- GO TO: `/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/UIManager.js`
- FIND: `function normalizePrefix(moduleName: string)`
- REPLACE WITH: `const normalizePrefix = function(moduleName: string)`

> **Step 3 | InitializeJavascriptAppEngine.js**

- GO TO: `node_modules\react-native\Libraries\JavaScriptAppEngine\Initialization\InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js`
- FIND: `function handleError(e, isFatal)`
- REPLACE WITH: `var handleError = function(e, isFatal)`

> **Step 4 | npm start -- --reset-cache**

after replacing all strings run `npm start -- --reset-cache` and it should work now

Comment: Hi Craig in RN 51.0 they fixed all functions =/ but still get this message.

Comment: this issue is usually related to babel and the use of strict mode not being enabled... maybe try this plugin?

[babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode)

Comment: Still not working...working only on debug mode, if I try => react-native run-android (without debug mode) or react-native run-android --variant=release I have the same issue with Strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

I just clean all plugins from .babelrc and works like charm.

Like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-native"
  ]
}
```

The reason for my problem was => "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"

Thanks for help Craig!